# "The given key was not present in the dictionary" ASP.NET error on IIS7

Tags: asp.net

I have this error on one of my sites. Searched thought all project found no Dictionary of some kind. Read somewhere it could be caused by URL Rewrite module on IIS 7 which i'm using for certain redirects.

Error appears on all pages thought the site, 99% sure only on pages that use URL Rewriting

This is the error's stack

```
at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFoundException() 
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2.get_Item(TKey key) 
at System.Data.DataView.System.Collections.IList.get_Item(Int32 recordIndex) 
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewPagedDataSource.EnumeratorOnIList.get_Current() 
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView.CreateItemsWithoutGroups(ListViewPagedDataSource dataSource, Boolean dataBinding, InsertItemPosition insertPosition, ArrayList keyArray) 
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView.CreateChildControls(IEnumerable dataSource, Boolean dataBinding) 
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data) 
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.OnDataSourceViewSelectCallback(IEnumerable data) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() 
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView.PerformSelect() 
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() 
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView.CreateChildControls() 
at System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() 
at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() 
at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() 
at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() 
at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() 
at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() 
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)HTTP_CONNECTION:Keep-Alive HTTP_ACCEPT:image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, application/x-shockwave-flash, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, application/x-icq, */* HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE:en HTTP_COOKIE:__utma=248870149.1673016949.1252234176.1276449788.1276595165.49; __utmz=248870149.1276595165.49.55.utmcsr=search|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=*****; wooTracker=C1T8MWMAZWQVHJXWROHB25SO4S0B7UO0; __utmb=248870149.6.10.1276595165; __utmc=248870149; wooTracker=C1T8MWMAZWQVHJXWROHB25SO4S0B7UO0; machine-id=87.69.44.154%3A1253914747956; wooMeta=ODAwMzkmMSYxJjc1MDE5JjEyNTUyMTQwODEwMjkmMTI1NTIxNDE1NjA0OCYmMTAwJiYzMDAyODQmJiYm; _csoot=1267959625296; _csuid=X4c1ef311c39a67; ASP.NET_SessionId=zzdn5b45uqyhw145ptqhxe20 HTTP_HOST:************ HTTP_REFERER:************* HTTP_USER_AGENT:Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; GTB6) HTTP_X_CEPT_ENCODING:gzip, deflate *************
```

**Is anyone familiar with fix or at least where to look for one ?**

Comment: do you know which page is causing this error?  if so, can you show the markup for the listview's in that page and their associated datasources?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stack trace points to the error occurring during databinding.  Could it be that in at least one case you're binding a list in your UI to a list of objects, datatable or other that does not contain a referenced column name?

Comment: how do i supposed to check that ?

Comment: The only way I know is to examine your code in cases where you're databinding.  The stack trace says it was a ListView control that was the culprit.  I'd start with listview controls that can potentially display a dynamic list of columns as that would be the highest probability of a sporadic problem.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this to your web.config configuration section:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
</system.webServer>
```

On pages that have rewritten url, normally not all managed modules are executed (no Authentication etc.). If the dictionary that is accessed would be filled from such a module (like HttpContext.Current.User, which is set in that way too and would be null without that setting), then this will fix it.

Comment: Hrm. Then I'm afraid there's no other way to debug into where the error occurs and find out what dictionary is missing which key, and try to reproduce from where the value is set in a non rewritten request. Then you can try to find out why the entry is not created in a rewritten request.

Comment: point is i cannot reproduce this error. Some users have it and i see large amount of these errors in my error reports page.

Answer (score 1):

it's hard to tell without more information, but I'd say you have a listview databound to a datasource that's doing a sql query, the binding includes picking off specific columns by name, and that column isn't in the result (column was renamed, column isn't in query, typo in binding, etc).

the markup for the listview, the datasource its bound to, and the codebehind for the datasource, is really what we need to help out here.